# C Project Euler Numbers Primes

Tags: c, primes

So,im resolving problem 10, and reach to one solution:

```
acu = 0;
for(i=2;i<=2000000;i++){        
    if(primo(i)== 1){
        acu = acu + i;
    }
}
```

where primo is :

```
int primo(long num){

long pd;

pd = num/2;

while(pd > 1 && num%pd != 0){
    pd--;
}
if (pd == 1)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;}
```

The time to executed in my machine was something like 700 seconds. Then i change this in the code:

```
int primo(long num){

long pd;

pd = lround(sqrt(num));

while(pd > 1 && num%pd != 0){
    pd--;
}
if (pd == 1)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;}
```

and the executed time was like 15 seconds. Why is so much difference between num/2 and lround(sqrt(num)) ?

Comment: You must know the concept of time complexity. When you execute your program through first method the complexity is O(n*n) while in second method it is O(n^3/2).

Comment: Why is so much difference between num/2 and lround(sqrt(num)) ? -->  difference between 1000000 and 1414.

Comment: @George the `sqrt` was *cheaper*, because it reduced the number of iterations.

Comment: @FernandoExequielOrquera You can further reduce the execution time by first checking for `2` (prime) and other even numbers (not prime) and then iterating only with **odd** numbers down to `3`.

Comment: If you want to explore further, Project Euler problem 10 can be solved in a fraction of a second using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and it is likely that you will not be able to solve later questions within the 1-minute rule without it.

Comment: You could also optimize your approach by saving the found primes.

Comment: the next *most significant* optimization probably is to not enumerate the candidates from `pd` *down* to 1, but rather enumerate them *up* from 1 to `pd`. a random number is much more likely to have smaller, rather than larger, factor.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cause in the worse case (when `num` is  prime) the first implementation will loop `num/2` times but the second will loop `sqrt(num)` times, and of course `sqrt(num)` is much lower than `num/2` so the time required by the second implementation is lower than the time required by the first one.

**EDIT :**

If you want another implementation faster than the two you used there is it :

```
int primo(long num){
    if(num==2) return 1; //2 is even but prime so we check it herer cause the next test will return 0 for even bumbers
    if(num%2==0) return 0; //if it is a multiple of 2 it is not a prime number so we do not loop in this case

    long nb_sqrt= lround(sqrt(num));
    if(nb_sqrt%2==0) nb_sqrt++; //start from an odd number (explained in the loop)

    while(num%nb_sqrt != 0) nb_sqrt-=2; //decrements by 2 since the number is not a multiple of 2 (already checkef) so it will not be divided by an even number 

    return nb_sqrt==1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the number of iterations of the `while` loop differ:

```
num = 2000000
# Number of iterations in case 1
num/2 =>  1000000

# Number of iterations in case 2
lround( sqrt(2000000)) = 1414
```

further, the `primo` is being called repeatedly in the for loop.